# get a substring preserving html tag inside

Tags: c#

A search procedure using full text search (it means: is hard to reproduce the match outside the procedure) return rows highlighting the matched string inside, like:

```
"i have been <em>match</em>ed"
"a <em>match</em> will happen in the word <em>match</em>"
"some random words including the word <em>match</em> here"
```

Now I need to get the first x characters of the string but I'm getting a few troubles with the html tags inside.

Like:

```
"i have been <em>mat</em>..." -> first 15 characters
"a <em>match</em> will happen in the word <em>m</em>..." -> first 33 characters
"some rando..." -> first 10 characters
```

I have tried using some if else, but I ended up with a big spaghetti.

Any tips?

Comment: Are the `<em>`s the only tags - i.e. is the rest plain text?

Comment: @EugenRieck yes. Anything else besides plain text is allowed to the user.

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry, is disallowed to the user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want based on there only being `<em>` tags.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbResults = GetMatches();
            var firstLine = HtmlSubstring(dbResults[0], 0, 15);
            Console.WriteLine(firstLine);
            var secondLine = HtmlSubstring(dbResults[1], 0, 33);
            Console.WriteLine(secondLine);
            var thirdLine = HtmlSubstring(dbResults[2], 0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(thirdLine);

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static List<string> GetMatches()
        {
            return new List<string>
            {
                "i have been <em>match</em>ed"
                ,"a <em>match</em> will happen in the word <em>match</em>"
                , "some random words including the word <em>match</em> here"
            };
        }

        private static string HtmlSubstring(string mainString, int start, int length = int.MaxValue)
        {
            StringBuilder substringResult = new StringBuilder(mainString.Replace("</em>", "").Replace("<em>", "").Substring(start, length));

            // Get indexes between start and (start + length) that need highlighting.
            int matchIndex = mainString.IndexOf("<em>", start);
            while (matchIndex > 0 && matchIndex < (substringResult.Length - start))
            {
                int matchIndexConverted = matchIndex - start;
                int matchEndIndex = mainString.IndexOf("</em>", matchIndex) - start;

                substringResult.Insert(matchIndexConverted, "<em>");
                substringResult.Insert(Math.Min(substringResult.Length, matchEndIndex), "</em>");

                matchIndex = mainString.IndexOf("<em>", matchIndex + 1);
            }

            return substringResult.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing a simple parser with a few states - `InText`, `InOpeningTag`, `InClosingTag` are a few that come to mind.

Just loop through the characters, figure out if you are `InText`, only counting those characters... Once you reach your limit, don't add any more text and if you are between opening and closing tags, just add the closing tag.

Take a look at the source code for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you don't know what I am talking about (look for the `Parse` methods).